# Should I answer a question and also flag it for deletion?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978823/how-to-run-performance-test-project-in-the-machine-where-visual-studio-is-not-in) is asking for some some software to perform a specific task. The answer is easy, so to help the asker I pointed them in the right direction with a comment. But the question seems off topic, so I also flagged it as such. Was that the correct approach?

Comment: I will often down vote all answers to a questions that **clearly** should be closed, as the answers are just making the site worse by engorging the questioner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the question is off topic and should be deleted, do not answer.

You can:

- Add a comment, pointing the user to the right site.
- Vote to close the question.
- If you can't vote to close, you can flag it.

If you give an answer you are sending the wrong signal to the user.